# Memory Requirement of Commons Math: The Apache Commons Mathematics Library

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-math

I would like to know if all the operations in Apache Commons Math are in memory operations.
I am particularly interested in OLSMultipleLinearRegression and using this for big data.

Also is there any existing JAVA API for running regression on big data.

Comment: Stephen's answer below looks pretty conclusive, but I'd suggest you also email the [commons user mailing list](http://commons.apache.org/mail-lists.html), prefixing your subject with `[math`], if you'd like to verify that with the developers. You'll get a quick response I'm sure (which you could post here for posterity).

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the [javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/OLSMultipleLinearRegression.html) for the `OLSMultipleLinearRegression` class is that it is entirely in memory.  For a start, the model and the sample data must be supplied as primitive arrays which precludes any possibility of representations that don't fit in memory ... at least at the point where you provide the inputs.

Comment: Thank you Stephen and Duncan for your inputs.
Is there any API which allows regression on big data without using memory.

Comment: I couldn't find one, but I didn't look very hard.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that `OLSMultipleLinearRegression` stores the full design matrix in memory.  There is another OLS implementation class, however,  `MillerUpdatingRegression`, in the same Commons Math package (version 3.0 onward) that does not store the input dataset in memory.